# Получение заголовка set-cookie xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, javascript, cookie, header, xmlhttprequest

Обрабатываю ответ от сервера:

```js
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    answer.innerHTML='<img src="loading.gif">';
    // назначаем асинхронный обработчик события
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

    answer.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;      // присваиваем содержимое
    document.getElementById("device").innerHTML= "Cookie: "+xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");            
    }
}
```

На сервере имеются такие заголовки:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();
session_name('RED');
header('Set-Cookie: '.session_name().'='.session_id());
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Set-Cookie');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie');
```

Ответ получается такой: `Cookie: null`.

Почему `getResponseHeader()` не возвращает заголовок `Set-Cookie`, явно разрешил `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie` и что еще?

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода и кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спецификация XHR в явном виде запрещает чтение заголовка `Set-Cookie`. Доступ к этому заголовку открывает слишком большой простор для уязвимостей. Поэтому **доступ целиком и полностью запрещён**.

Печенье следует жёстким правилам доступа, и предполагается, что заголовок `Set-Cookie` полностью обрабатывается браузером. После получения такого заголовка следует читать обновлённый `document.cookie`. Если печенье не обновилось, значит, оно предназначено не для вас.

Если вы хотите общаться с сервером с помощью печенья кросс-доменно, то можете добавить свой собственный заголовок и обрабатывать его так, как вам угодно. Назовите его `X-Redmal-Set-Cookie` и пользуйтесь им без каких-либо ограничений.

См. [xmlHttp.getResponseHeader + Not working for CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686769/xmlhttp-getresponseheader-not-working-for-cors).