# Angular: как прочитать заголовок у ответа?

Tags: javascript, http, angular2, typescript, angular4

Как прочитать заголовок у ответа, к примеру`Content-Type`? У меня это не получается сделать. Я пытаюсь хотя-бы отобразить все заголовки

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  readonly endpoint = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/login/';
  phpsessidCookieValue = '';

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
              private readonly cookieService: CookieService) { }

  post(userName: string, password: string) {    
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', userName)
      .set('password', password);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };

    return this.httpClient.post(this.endpoint, body, options)
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        console.log(response.headers); /*undefined*/
      });
  }
}
```

, **но мне в консоле говорят что** `response.headers = undefined`**. А в браузере видно, что во все не так**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может поможет `response.getAllResponseHeaders();`

Comment: @Puvvl говорит `response.getAllResponseHeaders is not a function`.

Comment: а `response.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")`

Comment: @Puvvl тут [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429458/14935](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429458/14935) говорят что доступ к `Set-Cookie` полностью закрыт. Но я попробовал `response.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')`: такая же ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения полного ответа со статусом и заголовками необходимо указать опцию `observe: 'response'`

```
this.httpClient.post(url, body, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.headers);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`headers`  - это часть класса [Response](https://angular.io/api/http/Response)

```
http.get('/path/to/resource')
    .subscribe((res:Response) => {
        console.log(res.headers);
});
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Все равно: `undefined`. Может ли это как-то связанно с тем, что у меня `POST-запрос`?